# I have created a login for my asp applocation but evertime I login it does not redirect me to the secure folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I login in my asp App I configured that it should take me to the Forms- Secure area. I added the role in the membership so that only Admin can see this option. But when I login with admin it requiers me to login again. Its like not recoginizing Im logged in.

THanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. What's the question? Do you have any code? We're not going to guess, I'm afraid. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormsAuthentication call SetAuthCookie and redirect.  Check the ReturnUrl querystring variable and redirect there or send the user into the default account page.

Also after you login, you could also use FireBug to insure the security cookie was set (the name is defined in the web.config) and if not, there are deeper issues.

Answer (score -1):

in the page load event add this hope it will work it works well in mvc not sure for asp.net

[Authorize(Roles="admin")]